# Menu based on URL

Tags: routes, uri

Is there way to show a menu based on the url provided?

For example:

```
sub1.test.com will provide menu A
sub2.test.com will provide menu B
```

Kind of a multisite principle but without using the actual multisite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:  https://drupal.org/project/domain

&               https://drupal.org/project/domain_menu_access

Using domain module you can manage various settings like theme, block for specific domain.

Using domain menu access you can restrict specific menu link to appear in specific domain under menu configuration settings.